# Div in front of another div

Tags: html, css

I need move container of site IN FRONT OF another div with background.
This is how it should looks like(ignore all other elements, just notice the background and container) -
[image: http://prntscr.com/7bfurw]

And this is how it looks now (wrong):
[image]

I was trying something with "position: absolute" and "top: x" and it "little works" but when i used magnifier in browser, it was completely scattered.

This is my actual code...
html:

```
<div class="horni-panel">
    <div class="logo">
        Zhlednuto.cz
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        Home, about atd.
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Mini pozadi -->
<div class="minipozadi">
    ahoj
</div>

<!-- hlavni obsah -->
<div class="container">
ahooj
</div>
```

and css:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Lato-Bold;
    src: url(fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf);
}

body
{
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.horni-panel
{
    border-top: 8px solid #34495e;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 77px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.logo
{
    color: #34495e;
    font-family: Lato-Bold;
    font-size: 33px;
}

.minipozadi
{
    height: 282px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

.container
{

    z-index: -1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Use margin-top: -120px;

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/sk6613gm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting your looking for this

http://output.jsbin.com/puladizire/2/

```
.minipozadi
{
    height: 282px;
    width: 100%;
    background:url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
}

.container
{

    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0 auto;
  position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
  margin-top:200px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I have added `margin` and `z-index` to the container